how to generate a flamegraph when using jeprof
I am using this command to generate jemolloc output svg file:
jeprof --svg texhub-server --base=texhub.out.1.0.i0.heap texhub.out.1.* > output.svg

I read document from here(https://github.com/GreptimeTeam/greptimedb/blob/develop/src/common/mem-prof/README.md) and it told that will generate flamegraph, but when I open the output.svg file, it was not a flamegraph. Am I missing something? I have tried to open the file with browser and inkspace.

this is the jeperf version info:
root@texhub-server-service-5c8fcf49d5-qrgh8:/app# jeprof --version
jeprof (part of jemalloc 5.2.1-0-gea6b3e973b477b8061e0076bb257dbd7f3faa756)
based on pprof (part of gperftools 2.0)

Copyright 1998-2007 Google Inc.

This is BSD licensed software; see the source for copying conditions
and license information.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


Sorry, I'm the author of that document. The content in develop branch is a little bit outdated and has been removed in #4810 . jeprof only generates memory consumption graph based on stack collapsing. To create the flamegraph, instead of:
jeprof --svg texhub-server --base=texhub.out.1.0.i0.heap texhub.out.1.* > output.svg

you will need the flamegraph.pl script:
jeprof --svg \
    texhub-server \
    --base=texhub.out.1.0.i0.heap \
    texhub.out.1.* \
    --collapsed | flamegraph.pl > output.svg

For more details, refer to this blog post: https://www.greptime.com/blogs/2024-01-18-memory-leak

Unknown option: collapse, did I use the wrong version of jeprof?

@Dolphin --collapsed

is there any docs of --collapsed option? I read the https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/libjemalloc-dev/jeprof.1.en.html and did not found any intro of this option. the --collapsed still did not work.

@Dolphin https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/blob/6092c980a6d02b34bc7b3ed0c2ad923d0a5d2970/bin/jeprof.in#L209
